# Why do this awk script print the original file too?

Tags: awk

I have following script:

**ascript2.awk**

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {FS=":"} 
a[$1]=a[$1] ";" $2 " : " $3
END{
for (x in a) print x,a[x]}
```

When I let it run, it prints also the original intput file. Why?
When I make a bash script like this it works fine:

**merge**

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F' *: *' '{a[$1]=a[$1] (a[$1]?" \\ " :" ; ") $2 ":" $3} END {for (x in a) print x,a[x]}' $1
```

Input:

```
Affe : 3 : test
Affe : 5 : test2
Money : 9 : test3
```

Outputs:

```
$ ./merge t.txt
Money  ; 9:test3
Affe  ; 3:test \ 5:test2

$ ./ascript2.awk t.txt
Affe : 3 : test
Affe : 5 : test2
Money : 9 : test3
Money  ; 9  :  test3
Affe  ; 3  :  test; 5  :  test2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `ascript2.awk`, `a[$1]=a[$1] ";" $2 " : " $3` should be enclosed in curly braces, otherwise it will be interpreted as a condition with no action, *and any condition without an action will print the line if and only the condition is met.* (See: [what is the meaning of 1 at the end of awk script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63891/what-is-the-meaning-of-1-at-the-end-of-awk-script)
)

So your script should look this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { FS=":" } 
{ a[$1] = a[$1] ";" $2 " : " $3 }
END { for (x in a) print x, a[x] }
```